# how to show small logo and hides the big images in stick using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to integrates a small images when the sticky menu appers  please see this link [clickheretoseemyproblem](http://haider.santabantathegreat.com/html/)

When we scrolldown you can see the sticky menu with small logo but it not good to see so i designed  a logo   need to replace if the sticky menu appears and hides that image

here the code i am working

```
<header class="header" id="home">    

<!-- COLOR OVER IMAGE -->
<div class="color-overlay"> <!-- To make header full screen. Use .full-screen class with color overlay. Example: <div class="color-overlay full-screen">  -->

    <!-- STICKY NAVIGATION -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse bs-docs-nav navbar-fixed-top sticky-navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- LOGO ON STICKY NAV BAR -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#kane-navigation">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo023.png" alt=""></a>

            </div>

            <!-- NAVIGATION LINKS -->
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="kane-navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-navigation">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#features">Sorrento Histology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#brief2">Sorrento Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#download">Products in Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#profile">Company Profile</a></li>
                    <!-- <li><a href="#screenshot-section">Screenshots</a></li> -->
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /END CONTAINER -->
    </div> <!-- /END STICKY NAVIGATION -->


    <!-- CONTAINER -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- ONLY LOGO ON HEADER -->
        <div class="only-logo">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" style="width:312px;height:187px">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /END ONLY LOGO ON HEADER -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                <!-- HEADING AND BUTTONS -->
                <div class="intro-section">

                    <!-- WELCOM MESSAGE -->
                    <h1 class="intro">Welcome to Haider Biologics</h1>
                    <h5>Want to know more?</h5>

                    <!-- BUTTON -->
                    <div class="buttons" id="download-button">

                        <a href="#download" class="btn btn-default btn-lg standard-button"><i class="icon-app-download"></i>Click Here</a>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /END BUTTONS -->

                </div>
                <!-- /END HEADNING AND BUTTONS -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /END ROW -->

    </div>
    <!-- /END CONTAINER -->
</div>
<!-- /END COLOR OVERLAY -->
</header>
<!-- /END HEADER -->
```

Comment: where is script that you have tried?

Comment: not working when you see on top left logo is getting if sticky is not also can we hide that it should show when sticky header comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default on page load write this line

```
$(".navbar-brand").css("display","none");
```

And then add this following code snippet

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(top>=100){
       $(".navbar-brand").css("display","block");
    }
    else{
       $(".navbar-brand").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

**write all the code snippet in**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: not working when you see on top left logo is getting if sticky is not also can we hide that it should show when sticky header comes

Comment: did you see the link i gave in that on top left you see a logo it visible if the sticky menu is not there then i want to show that logo  if the sticky menu  appears

Comment: bydefault the small logo should be hidden and when the sticky menu appears it should be shown .. Is it what you want?